# Magento 2.3.2 Google reCAPTCHA v3 very slow

Tags: magento2.3.2, recaptcha, mageplaza

I am using **mageplaza google recaptcha** in login, create user,forgot pass an so, But while doing any operation the **recaptcha** load very slow, and user submits data before **captcha** reload. Hence user often get **recaptcha** invalid issue.

How may i load **recptcha** with page load.

I used

```
$(".action.captcha-reload").trigger("click");
jQuery( "captcha-button-selector" ).trigger( "click" );
```

I used this two solutions.But no help.

Answer (score 4):

From Magento 2.3.x, no need to installed extension for Google ReCaptcha. Magento provides inbuilt functionality for Google ReCaptcha. Find Admin Settings to enable.

> Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Security ->
>   Google reCaptcha -> Make It Enable

Add ****Google API website key** & **Google API secret key**** in General Section.

Comment: yes i did. But it showing ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type.. there is no recaaptcha type V3 setting in magento 2.3.2

Comment: There are two types of Google ReCaptcha available. reCaptcha V2 and Invisible reCaptcha.

Comment: yes i have added invisible captcha.Now working fine in firefox. But chrome ,it takes to much time. Sometimes user fills the data and submit.Hence error comes. captach not found.

Comment: Can you please share error screen shot?

Comment: there is no error. Just that captcha is invisible

Comment: I have added screensot.There are other issues.But no issue regarding recaptcha. And recaptcha  working and loading fine in firefox. But not in chrome.

Comment: Issue may be in Console Warning: JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated. Need to change from load to on load like
jQuery(window).on(‘load’, function() {

Comment: ok.but working fine in firefox. issue with chrome.  And how to solve  Warning: JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated.. this

Comment: Find the js and change there with on load function.